# Why I get error while building Angular package with singleton class?

Tags: angular, typescript, signalr

I'm trying to create to make **Angular** library, in this library; I created a singleton class to deal with the same **SignalR** connection, here's my code:

```
import * as signalR from '@microsoft/signalr';

export class SignalRConnection {

    static _instance: SignalRConnection;

    connection: signalR.HubConnection;

    private constructor() {
        this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl("http://localhost:5000/hub")
            .build();

        // TODO: something on reject
        this.connection.start().catch(console.log);
    }

    /**
     * Get exists or create a new instance of SignalR connection
     */
    static getOrCreate(): SignalRConnection {
        if (SignalRConnection._instance == undefined) {
            SignalRConnection._instance = new SignalRConnection();
        }
        return SignalRConnection._instance;
    }
}
```

This code works as expected while development (I use it using `public-api`), but when I tried to build the package, I got this error:

```
error encountered
in metadata generated for exported symbol 'SignalRConnection':
Metadata collected contains an error that will be reported at runtime: Only initialized variables and constants can be referenced because the value
of this variable is needed by the template compiler.
```

What changed while compiling, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
export class SignalRConnection implements OnInit {

    static _instance: any = null;

   ngOnInit() {
        SignalRConnection._instance= this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.